# Body with height 100% with background-image: cover to fill enire page not just a viewport - without js if possible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image]

Is it possible to have background image cover the entire page even if the viewport is smaller than the page, only with css?

btw I have to setup html,body to 100% height.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **100vh** height and background-size: cover; it will cover full page this will work

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but using vh is unfortunately not an option, due to client's request and cross-browser compatibility:
http://caniuse.com/#search=vh

Comment: Try to use this one this is working for me  background: url(../img/background.jpg) no-repeat top center fixed;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: #61513b;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    min-width: 1020px;
    overflow: hidden;

Comment: It works with background-attachment:fixed, but not with scroll